Getting the formular of a summation
im kind of stuck at my math homework from my calculus class. To progress further i need to be able to write a Summation into a forumular(?), as seen in the picture. Is there any proven method to do this? Right now ofcourse i could use wolframalpha, but how would i do this in an exam by hand?
Thanks
Picture of the summation and the formular i need to get to
Left side is what is given, right side is needed
